# Problem regarding aligning the textViews with their bottom edges in straight line

Tags: android, xml

I am new to android and while making a starting layout, i just got stuck with the alignment of the bottom edges of the two textViews in a single straight line without some hard coding(like defining fixed sp values to align the two).
Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/time_text_view"
        android:text="2:10"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/time_text_view"
        android:text="PM"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's what the looks like after compiling:

I want to align 'PM' and the time on the same base **but not on the base of the layout.**
[image]

Comment: You want PM to center to the time ?

Comment: Not centering but imagine drawing a line where the base of time is and then writing PM above the same line as the base.

Comment: My advice to you is to start your android with the latest library. For example instead of using `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` use `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with `ConstraintLayout` as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2:10"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PM"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/time_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/time_text_view" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Or with `RelativeLayout` as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2:10"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/time_text_view"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/time_text_view"
        android:text="PM"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is showing the text at the bottom of the layout but not aligning the PM text with the base of the text that is representing time. I want those two to be aligned but not with the layout's base rather starting from the top left corner itself. Thanks!

Comment: This works perfectly fine. I don't have any knowledge of constraint layout up until now, so i want to ask if i can do this with relative layout in any way?

Comment: Yes we can do it with RelativeLayout as well. @VaibhavDixit

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it then, I would appreciate the help!

Comment: Thanks I got the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with `ConstraintLayout` by assigning:

- left/start horizontal constraint of "PM" to right/end of "2:10"
- bottom vertical constraint of "PM" to bottom of "2:10"

  ```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/time_text_view"
      android:text="2:10"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textSize="40sp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/timePostfixTextView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/time_text_view"
      android:text="PM"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/timeTextView"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/timeTextView" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Updated code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2:10"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PM"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: this doesn't work because this code only modifies the height to match_parent and that won't do anything with alignment of the text.

Comment: Sorry my bad, My code works with linear layout. Editing the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

just use below line in your second TextView

```
<TextView
       ....
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/time_text_view"
       ......../>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Wrap them inside a `LinerarLayout` like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/time_text_view"
            android:text="2:10"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/time_text_view"
            android:text="PM"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```